# Add floating button at the center of image

Tags: html, css, button, css-float, center

I have the following div tag, which displays an image and beneath the image, adds a text that appears in the center.

Question - I would like add a floating button 'Test Me' at the center of the Image. Any response appreciated ?

Test

CSS -

```
div.ImgDiv
{
    width:275;height:155
    }

 #paragraphName
 {  
    margin-left:120px;
    margin-top:0px
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give your button a width and `margin:0 auto;` for left-right centering.